# Copying files with CMD

Tags: cmd

I have one folder in which there is a txt file that generates every 30 minutes and overwrites the previous version of it. I wish to create a backup folder where a copy of the txt file will be held, for that to happen I want a cmd file that basically copies the file and adds the timestamp at the end of the new file (I will even settle for a serial number at the end of the file.) This cmd file I will run using task scheduler of windows.

I tried using the robocopy command but it doesn't seem to create new files but only copy once and keep overwriting over it.

So basically: a command that will copy File.txt -> File_timestamp.txt every 15 minutes without overwriting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a command you can use to make a copy of the file with a timestamp in another directory. When you are confident that the file will be copied correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Copy-Item` cmdlet.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "Move-Item -Path .\yyy.txt -Destination C:\temp\yyy_$(Get-Date -UFormat '%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M') -WhatIf"
```